# What does "passit" mean?

Tags: vocabulary

I encountered the word "passit" in the following statement by Lucretius:

```
Accidere ex una flamma parva incendia passit.
```

I cannot find the word *passit* in dictionaries. What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

This seems to be a misquotation (not least because it doesn't scan). The intended line is presumably *De Rerum Natura* 5.609: *accidere ex una scintilla incendia passim*, "[we see] fires happen everywhere from one small spark".

Comment: A Google search shows a surprising number of people misquoting this line. How on earth did that happen?